# Do PS3s have a Java VM - if yes, then is it ME or EE,?

Tags: java, playstation3

Based on my investigation, I can see a "Java Enabled" option on the credits screen under settings. Does this mean PS3 has a Java VM? Is it Java ME or Java EE?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PS3 (and PS4 and XB1) has a JVM.
This is because they all feature a Blu-ray Player, and all Blu-ray Players runs Java as part of the Blu-ray specification.

It is called **Blu-ray Disc Java** and is abbreviated **BD-J**.

And yes, because of this you can in fact code small homebrew games in Java which runs on all 3 consoles (and future ones as well) from the very same disc. That was one of the many goals with BD-J.

**A few YouTube example videos of various BD-J Xlets running on PS3:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_E9VaXywG0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxMpLB_ZsDs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKadWBm9CQA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bC5FV-2AY4

**A few useful links:**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javame/bluray-142687.html

http://www.tvwithoutborders.com/

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=38044.0